# opencv with firewire camera under linux

Tags: linux, opencv

My confusion has to do with the major/minor number of the device drivers as they relate to using VideoCapture() routine (my development environment is ubuntu 10.10).

When the OpenCV documentation says "camera index" Is it referring to the minor number of the /dev/video0 device?  So when I instantiate using VideoCapture(0), it will use the first /dev/video0 driver?

What happens when I have a firewire camera in addition to a USB camera? My firewire camera uses the /dev/raw1394 device but it has a different mayor number but the same minor
number of 0.

So, my question is basically how do you specify devices (not "camera index" or default camera) for the VideoCapture ctor?

thanks,

-Andres

Comment: Great question. You can look into the OpenCV implementation. What code is executed when you pass that index and how to enumerate in linux for video input devices. In Windows there's a special function for that. Devices has numbers from 0. What about Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to capture image from FireWire cam using OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822032/unable-to-capture-image-from-firewire-cam-using-opencv)

Comment: OpenCV is not compiled with CMU camera support by default, but it supports it. You will need to enable this feature and recompile OpenCV. Check the link I shared above.

Comment: thank you for your responses drweb86 and karlphillip.  Your comment/answers are always very useful and much appreciated