# Need Help Showing Video from Firewire Camera Using Java Opencv 2.4.9 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, opencv, firewire

I can show video from a USB webcam, but when I try to show video from a firewire camera, I get the following erorr:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be > 0

I have used Coriander and can see video from the firewire camera through there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, OpenCV is not compiled with **CMU** camera support by default, but it supports it. You can [try to enable this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7823387/176769) and rebuild OpenCV.

Another alternative requires to [use **libdc1394** to retrieve frames](http://www.developerstation.org/2011/05/setup-ieee-1394-camera-with-opencv.html), and then convert that data to a `Mat`.