# Capture from firewire camera (with CMU1394 driver) using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, firewire

I’m trying to acquire video from a DCAM1394 camera using OpenCV (C++) on Win 7 (64bit). I tried **VideoCapture**, but it seems only works on webcam instead of the firewire camera. Then I found [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822032/unable-to-capture-image-from-firewire-cam-using-opencv); following its idea, I installed the **CMU1394 driver** for my firewire camera, and tried to recompile opencv.

Below is How I did it:

**STEP1:** Install the CMU1394 driver by running the file [1394camera646.exe](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~iwan/1394/downloads/index.html), and then run the demo provided by the publisher; it worked just fine, which I think proves that the driver has been installed successfully.

**STEP2:** Then I open the file "{where you extract opencv}...\sources\modules\highgui\src\cap_cmu.cpp" ([as shown in the Fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02nhh.png)), and add "#def HAVE_CMU1394 1" right before "#ifdef HAVE_CMU1394", in hope of letting the codes after "#ifdef HAVE_CMU1394" to be compiled.

**STEP3:** After the revision of "**cap_cmu.cpp**", I configure and generate files from source using **Cmake**, and compile the output using VS2013 Express. Here an error popped up: "**cannot open include file "1394camera.h**"".

Normally, the file **"1394camera.h"** is not precompiled in OpenCV by default; the error popped up due to adding "#def HAVE_CMU1394 1" before "#ifdef HAVE_CMU1394" (which is exactly what I want to do).  OpenCV source doesn't have the file **"1394camera.h"**, and it is provided by the CMU1394 in its source file **1394camera646_src**.

So, my question is:

**1)** Am I conducting the right procedure by "Install CMU1394 -> Recompile OpenCV"?;

**2)** I know that the recompiling fails because the compiler cannot find "**1394camera.h**". But How can I include that file (and other .h/.cpp files in **1394camera646_src**) in OpenCV source file and compile them together?

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1 add the header files

```
#include "precomp.hpp";
#include "cvconfig.h";
```

you may find the cvconfig.h file in the project directory generated by CMake.

#### Step 2 add the source file `cap_cmu.cpp` to your project

#### Step 3 link the proper library (e.g. `cmu1394.lib`)

May the <kbd>force</kbd> be with you~